# How to save the userID of users from DB to my sharedpreference?

Tags: php, android, mysql

I'm using php and mysql for my login an I want also the userid of the logged in user will be saved on the sharedpreference. I don't know how to do it.
Here is my php login.

### Login.php

```
    <?php 
require 'database-config.php';

session_start();

$username = "";
$password = "";

if(isset($_POST['username'])){
$username = $_POST['username'];
}
if (isset($_POST['password'])) {
$password = $_POST['password'];
}
if (isset ($_SESSION['userID'])){
$userID = $_SESSION['userID'];
}


$q = 'SELECT * FROM tbl_user WHERE username=:username AND password=:password';

$query = $dbh->prepare($q);

$query->execute(array(':username' => $username, ':password' => $password));


if($query->rowCount() == 0){
header('Location: Login.php?err=1');
}else{

$row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
session_regenerate_id();
$_SESSION['sess_user_id'] = $row['userID'];
$_SESSION['sess_username'] = $row['username'];
$_SESSION['sess_userrole'] = $row['roles'];

session_write_close();

if( $_SESSION['sess_userrole'] == "renter"){
echo "renter";
echo $_SESSION['sess_user_id'];

}else if ($_SESSION['sess_userrole'] == "owner"){
echo "owner";
echo $_SESSION['sess_user_id'];

}
}
?>
```

And this is how I save the username and password to sharedpreference.

```
if (!username.equals("") && (!password.equals(""))) {
        PostResponseAsyncTask task1 = new PostResponseAsyncTask(MainActivity.this, postData,
                new AsyncResponse() {
                    @Override
                    public void processFinish(String s) {

                if (s.contains("renter")) {
                    Log.d(TAG, s);
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Renter Login Successful!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Intent in = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ListActivity.class);
                    startActivity(in);

                    finish();

                } else if (s.contains("owner")) {
                    Log.d(TAG, s);
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Owner Login Successful!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Intent in = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ownerhome.class);
                    startActivity(in);
                    finish();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Login Failed!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                    }
                });
        task1.execute("http://carkila.esy.es/authenticate.php");

    }

    btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            HashMap postData = new HashMap();

            postData.put("username", etUsername.getText().toString());
            postData.put("password", MD5.encrypt(etPassword.getText().toString()));

            PostResponseAsyncTask task1 = new PostResponseAsyncTask(MainActivity.this, postData,
                    new AsyncResponse() {
                        @Override
                        public void processFinish(String s) {
                            Log.d(TAG,s);
                            if (s.contains("renter")) {
                                if (checkFlag) {

                                    editor.putString("username", etUsername.getText().toString());
                                    editor.putString("password", MD5.encrypt(etPassword.getText().toString()));

                                    editor.apply();

                                    Log.d(TAG, pref.getString("password", ""));
                                }

                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Renter Login Successful!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                Intent in = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ListActivity.class);
                                startActivity(in);
                                finish();

                            } else if (s.contains("owner")) {

                                if (checkFlag) {


                                    editor.putString("username", etUsername.getText().toString());
                                    editor.putString("password", MD5.encrypt(etPassword.getText().toString()));

                                    editor.apply();
                                }

                                editor.putString("username", etUsername.getText().toString());
                                editor.putString("password", MD5.encrypt(etPassword.getText().toString()));
                                editor.apply();

                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Owner Login Successful!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                Intent in = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ownerhome.class);
                                startActivity(in);
                                finish();
                            } else {
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Login Failed!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }


                        }
                    });
            task1.execute("http://carkila.esy.es/authenticate.php");
        }
```

And this is the database my database from a server.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QK1Il.png)

Comment: Seems like you have already done that??

Comment: Only the username and password is saved to the sharedpreference sir. @Jas

Comment: Post your code where you are getting your user id

Comment: @Jas - Uh, but I don't have it sir.  The php code posted is the only way i got username and password...

Comment: Show us the response you are getting when your login is successful

Comment: `08-08 20:19:44.883 27380-27380/com.example.kun.carkila D/com.example.kun.carkila.MainActivity: owner1`       
`08-08 20:19:44.913 27380-27380/com.example.kun.carkila D/com.example.kun.carkila.ownerhome: owner
08-08 20:19:44.913 27380-27380/com.example.kun.carkila D/com.example.kun.carkila.ownerhome: 202cb962ac59075b964b07152d234b70`

Comment: `owner1` is the userRole and the ID.
the `owner` on the 2nd Log is the `username` and next is the password sir.

Comment: No. You will get a response from your server when clicking your login button right? How are you getting it?

Answer (score 0):

```
public static final String pref_name = "your shared preference name";
    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(pref_name, MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor prefEditor = settings.edit();
    prefEditor.putString("userId", userId);
    prefEditor.commit();
```

Hopes this code helps you

Answer (score 0):

Save the user id similarly

```
String userId = "your user id string from server";

editor.putString("user id", userId);
editor.apply();
```

Comment: The `Int` is giving me an error it says I should do it as `String`.